# Storing a value in order to allow to iterate - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to come up with the simplest average program but I keep bumping into 2 problems:

1st - how to store a value in order to allow it to iterate afterwards?

2nd - I believe I'm incurring in a double counting issue here. How could I avoid that?(I tried to put an example but ****** stack overflow keeps mistakenly addressing my example as code  and asking to format it properly so I ended up removing it altogether....

Btw, are these sort of questions covered in a Computer Science specific class? Or it's something that you learn just by reading the language's documentation?

Thanks in advance!

```js
function average(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    var sum;
    var current = array[i];
    var next = array[i + 1];
    var sum = current + next;
  }
  console.log(sum / array.length);
}

var arrX = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

average(arrX);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some logical mistakes in your code as far as i can see.

There are lot's of ways to find average of a number array.
First one kind the one you tried.

```js
function average(array) {
  var sum = 0; // keep sum outside of for loop
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i]; // add each child to sum
  }
  // console.log(sum / array.length); //either console it or
  return sum / array.length; // return it back
}

var arrX = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

var av = average(arrX); // get value if returned.

console.log(av);
```

Also what you can use a `reduce` function

```
var arrX = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
var average = arrX.reduce((sum, child) => sum + child, 0) / arrX.length;
console.log(average);
```

See how to use reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

After all I'm guessing you would maybe check the basics of javascript.

[freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/) is really good source if you want to check

Answer (score 0):

Here's `average`:

```js
function average(array){
  return array.reduce((a,v)=>a+v)/array.length;
}
console.log(average([5, 10, 15, 20, 25]));
```

Answer (score 0):

"simply" do

```js
const average = arr => arr.reduce((tot,val)=>tot+val) / arr.length

console.log( average([5, 10, 15, 20, 25]) )  // 15
```

by using [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

this is just a story about long learning and a lot of exercises

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you want to store the value of 'sum' to use later. To do that you either need to declare sum outside of the for loop and return it at the end of function, or you need to declare it outside of the function.

Also, if you wanted to make a function that finds the average of all the elements inside the array you need to write something like this:

```
function (array) {
   let sum = 0;
   for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
       sum = sum + array[i];
   }
   let average = sum/array.length;
   return average;
}
```